# 'Undefined Is Not A Function' while using arrays in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cheerio

I am running node with cheerio. I have this function which needs to display an attribute value of an element contained in an array.

```js
for (var row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    console.log("Row Length: " + array[row].length);
    for (var col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        console.log("Inside:");
        console.log(array[row][col].getAttribute('val'));        
    }
}
```

My array contains list items populated using `push`

```js
array.push($('[title!="CATA"][collection="items"]'));
```

I get the desired output for 'Row Length', and it displays 'Inside', but then displays 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'. I have tried to use .attr('val') too but with the same error.

Executing console.log(array[row][col]) gives me the following.

```js
{ type: 'tag',
  name: 'li',
  attribs: 
   { id: 'Amber',
     collection: 'items',
     title: 'disk',
     val: '10|9|2|10|7|13|2|10|12|2|2|5|3|3|5|2|8|7|5|10|4|6|6|3|4|6|2|8|11|2|10|7|9|9|10|8' },
  children: 
   [ { data: 'disk : 10|9|2|10|7|13|2|10|12|2|2|5|3|3|5|2|8|7|5|10|4|6|6|3|4|6|2|8|11|2|10|7|9|9|10|8',
       type: 'text',
       next: null,
       prev: null,
       parent: [Circular] } ],
  next: 
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'li',
     attribs: 
      { id: 'Amber',
        collection: 'items',
        title: 'usb',
        val: '3|3|2|4|2|4|3|3|3|13|5|13|2|13|2|5|5|3|4|3|6|3|2|2|5|13|2|3|2|13|2|13|2|2|13|4' },
     children: [ [Object] ],
     next: 
     .
     .
     .
```

All I am trying to do is to access the 'val'.

Comment: Did you print array[0][0] element? You are experting HTML element, but I doubted array not holding HTML element at array[0][0] index.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the error is produced by this line

```
console.log(array[row][col].getAttribute('val'));
```

You are calling .getAttribute on a non-object. Give a full listing.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I am trying to get the JQuery code to work on node with cheerio. I understand that cheerio and JQuery are different, but I need some help with accessing the attribute of an element stored in an array.

Comment: @NeelDeveloper You're going to have to supply some example HTML code and what you want your selector to actually pick out if that is the help you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```js
console.log(array[row][col].attribs.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

One or more values in your array is `undefined` and when you call `getAttribute` on it the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` is thrown. To debug this look at the data inside the array by using `console.log(array)` or using a debugger. Ultimately the jQuery function is populating the array with unassigned variables so review the selector and see if it doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

First, print a more useful message:

```
if (!array[row][col] || !(array[row][col].getAttribute)) {
    console.log(row, col, array[row][col]);
}
```

Now look on your console and you'll see the indices for which your array is not filled with the kinds of objects you expect, as well as those objects.